# os.path.isdir() gives always true

Tags: python-2.7, os.path

Hi I write a simple python code it will check folder/dir is exist or not in the /usr/share/* file but it's fail to check

```
import  os 
try:
     os.path.isdir('/usr/share/sqlmap')
     print 'sqlmap found'
except OSError:
     print "Sqlmap not found"
#Output
 sqlmap found
```

Although it's not exist in my that directory. Please anyone tell me where my mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) isn't very clear about this, but `isdir` would return `False` if the directory doesn't exist. It wouldn't throw an exception. Therefore it would be more appropriate for you to use an if-else block in this case.

For example:

```
import  os 
if os.path.isdir('/usr/share/sqlmap'):
    print 'sqlmap found'
else:
    print "Sqlmap not found"
```

Comment: Instead of using `=='False'` you can rather use the `not` keyword, e.g. `if not os.path.isdir(...`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect an error to be thrown, use:

```
import  os 
if os.path.isdir('/usr/share/sqlmap'):
    print 'sqlmap found'
else:
    print "Sqlmap not found"
```